# how to use useState inside inner function scope in react.js hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am completely new to react.js.

I am fetching async data from my server that uses express.js. After I get that data I want to set my house parameters when I open that page for the first time.

```
const Houses = () => {
    const [house, setHouse] = useState({});

    ...

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = () => {
            fetch('http://localhost:9000/houses')
                .then(res => res.text())
                .then(res => {
                    if (res) {
                        let houseData = JSON.parse(res);
                        console.log(houseData); // server res prints correctly - prints: { name: 'sweet house', address: 'fukuoka hakata' }
                        setHouse({...house, houseData});
                        console.log(house); // doesnt change after sethouse - prints : {}
                    }
                });
        }

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    ...
}
```

Im getting the data from my server without any problem.
The problem is that the house parameters dont get updated. I know its a different scope, what I need to know is how I do it in this case. Thanks

Comment: Are you retrieving a single house object from that endpoint or an array of houses? If the latter, you should modify the `useState` to be `const [ houses, setHouses ] = useState([])` then conditionally `setHouses( [ ...houses, houseData ])` then render if length > 1.  If you are actually just retrieving the object, you can conditionally render by checking `isEmpty` by importing lodash or is `Object.hasOwnProperty(whateverProp)`

Comment: what do you mean different scope? setHouse will still be available.. did you check what is in `res`?

Comment: How do you know `house` parameter does not get updated ?
Try console logging `house` before component return statement

Comment: You cannot access the state immediately after setting it, `setHouse` will be batched

Comment: if `houseData` is an Object , you can directly set `setHouse(houseData)`

Comment: Hey Chan, that was it. Changging to setHouse(houseData); worked for me. If you add answer I choose your answer as right. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the `house` state immediately after setting it, `setHouse` may be batched.

See more of State: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

You are trying to do

```
let houseData = JSON.parse(res);
 // houseData =  { name: 'sweet house', address: 'fukuoka hakata' }
setHouse({ ...house, houseData: houseData });
```

instead of `setHouse(houseData)`. Since `houseData` is an Object, you can directly set it.

**Replace**

```
setHouse({...house, houseData})
```

**with**

```
setHouse(houseData)
```

Comment: Excellent. but even in this state, your first comment says the state can't be accessed after of setting, immediately. Then still consol.log returns {}?

Comment: Yes, it will still log `{}`.